# Group (pivot) a 2d array by one column and sum values by another column in respective groups

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have a multidimensional array that has a date, name, & markup.

```
$in = [
    [
        'saledate' => '2016-02-01',
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'markup' => 561
    ],
    [
        'saledate' => '2016-02-01',
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'markup' => 681
    ],
    [
        'saledate' => '2016-02-02',
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'markup' => 379
    ],
    [
        'saledate' => '2016-02-01',
        'name' => 'Jane Doe',
        'markup' => 205
    ],
    [
        'saledate' => '2016-02-02',
        'name' => 'Jane Doe',
        'markup' => 900
    ],
    [
        'saledate' => '2016-02-02',
        'name' => 'Jane Doe',
        'markup' => 787
    ],
    [
        'saledate' => '2016-02-03',
        'name' => 'Jane Doe',
        'markup' => 211
    ]
]
```

I'm trying to sum the values for each person by date for the desired output:

```
 0 => 
array (size=3)
  'name' => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
  '2016-02-01' => float 1242
  '2016-02-02' => float 379
 1 => 
array (size=3)
  'name' => string 'Jane Doe' (length=8)
   '2016-02-01' => float 205
   '2016-02-02' => float 1687
   '2016-02-03' => float 211
```

Here is what I have but I think I'm just confusing myself...

```
 $out = array();
 foreach ($in as $row)
 {
   $result[$row['saledate']]['saledate'] = $row['saledate'];
   $result[$row['name']]['name'] = $row['name'];
   $result[$row['date']]['markup'] += $row['markup'];
 }
 $out = array_values($out);
```

Comment: be aware of overwriting your saledate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the `name` as the key in your output array, it'll make grouping the results easier:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($in as $row) {

  /* set the key using the name, eg. $out['John Doe'] */
  if (! isset($out[$row['name']])) {
    $out[$row['name']] = array('name' => $row['name']); 
  }

  /* if the saledate isn't already exist, set it */
  if (! isset($out[$row['name']][$row['saledate']])) {
    $out[$row['name']][$row['saledate']] = 0;    
  }

  /* add the markup */
  $out[$row['name']][$row['saledate']] += $row['markup'];

}
```

Which would give you:

```
Array
(
    [John Doe] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [2016-02-01] => 1242
            [2016-02-02] => 379
        )

    [Jane Doe] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jane Doe
            [2016-02-01] => 205
            [2016-02-02] => 1687
            [2016-02-03] => 211
        )

)
```

If you don't want the `name` key, just use `$out = array_values($out)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```php
$result = array();

array_walk(
    $in,
    function ($row) use (&$result) {
        $key = array_search($row['name'], array_column($result, 'name'));
        if ($key === False) {
            $key = array_push($result, array('name' => $row['name'])) - 1;
        }
        $date = $row['saledate'];
        if (!isset($result[$key][$date]))
            $result[$key][$date] = $row['markup'];
        else
            $result[$key][$date] += $row['markup'];
    }
    ,
    $result
);

print_r($result);
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/WM2Mc)**</kbd>

After init an empty array, we pass it by reference as second arguments to `array_walk`: inside the called function, we check if the name and date already exists: if it is, we add the current value, otherwise we create new element(s) with current value.

---

- See more about [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)
- See more about [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) PHP > 5.5
- See more about [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning temporary first level keys to the result array can be avoided by pushing reference variables into the result array then manipulating only the references as needed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1lI7q))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($in as ['saledate' => $s, 'name' => $n, 'markup' => $m]) {
    if (!isset($ref[$n])) {
        $ref[$n] = ['name' => $n, $s => $m];
        $result[] = &$ref[$n];
    } else {
        $ref[$n][$s] = ($ref[$n][$s] ?? 0) + $m;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```